# Resize polygon maintaining position - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

So I have this svg that has multiple polygons inside, what I want to accomplish is to animate one polygon inside it (resize it with easing) such that it doesn't move from its place. Considering that the polygon position is set by `points="..."` (i guess..).

I want to do this preferably in jQuery or CSS but plain JavaScript works too or any other libraries..

Here is an example:

shapes.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-47 49 404 404" style="enable-background:new -47 49 404 404;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#154E78;}
    .st1{fill:#006496;}
    .st2{fill:#047EBE;}
    .st3{fill:#CD99B2;}
    .st4{fill:#D464A4;}
    .st5{fill:#CC78B1;}
</style>
<polygon id="XMLID_14_" class="st0" points="213.4,177 241.1,129 268.9,177 "/>
<polygon id="XMLID_13_" class="st1" points="240.2,129 212.4,177 184.7,129 "/>
<polygon id="XMLID_15_" class="st2" points="156,177 183.7,129 211.4,177 "/>
<polygon id="XMLID_20_" class="st3" points="98.6,177 126.3,129 154,177 "/>
<polygon id="XMLID_22_" class="st4" points="41.1,177 68.9,129 96.6,177 "/>
<polygon id="XMLID_29_" class="st5" points="125.3,129 97.6,177 69.8,129 "/>
</svg>
```

preview:
[shapes.svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJr9U.png)

what I want to accomplish is:
[resized.svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpgZv.png)

By resizing the 2nd polygon inside the svg

I dont have enough reputation to show you what happens if I scale it to 1.3 for example, but what happens is that the polygon moves along the artboard.

Comment: A simple scale transform (e.g. <polygon id="XMLID_29_" class="st5" points="125.3,129 97.6,177 69.8,129 " transform="scale(1.5)"/>) will scale the polygon points away from the origin. You want to scale the polygon points away from the center of the polygon. You can accomplish this using a transform that translates polygon center to origin, scales, and then translates polygon center back to initial location (e.g. <polygon id="XMLID_29_" class="st5" points="125.3,129 97.6,177 69.8,129 " transform="translate(97.55,153) scale(1.5) translate(-97.55,-153)"/>
).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, yes that makes sense in a way, how do you get the numbers tho? the translation (97.55, 153)? i guess those are to center to origin, but how did you get them, in case I have another svg?
(so that I can understand the process)

Comment: EDIT: Just realized it, you think about the edges in the svg and struggle to find the middle point in my case ( (125.3 + 69.8) / 2 ), ( ( 177 + 129 ) / 2 ). Thank you very much! Can you post it as Answer? or should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple scale transform (e.g. `<polygon id="XMLID_29_" class="st5" points="125.3,129 97.6,177 69.8,129 " transform="scale(1.5)"/>`) will scale the polygon points away from the origin. You want to scale the polygon points away from the center of the polygon. You can accomplish this using a transform that translates polygon center to origin, scales, and then translates polygon center back to initial location (e.g. `<polygon id="XMLID_29_" class="st5" points="125.3,129 97.6,177 69.8,129 " transform="translate(97.55,153) scale(1.5) translate(-97.55,-153)"/>`). In this example, I am using the center of the polygon's bounding rectangle as the center of the polygon (i.e.(125.3+69.8)/2=97.55, (129+177)/2=153).